# R - RW metropolis using gibbs fails

Tags: mcmc, random-walk

I want to sample from the posterior, where LambdaA and LambdaB are exponential rates of A and B. Also, y is the observations of the r.v.'s.

The posterior is given by

[image]

and for numerical reasons, i am taking the log of this function.

Data:

```
n<-100
y<- c(rexp(n))
```

Logarithm of posterior:

```
dmix<-function(LambdaA,LambdaB,w){


ifelse( LambdaA<=0|LambdaB<=0|w<0|w>1 ,0,log(w*LambdaA*LambdaB*exp(-2*(LambdaA+LambdaB))*prod(w*LambdaA*exp(-
LambdaA*y) + (1-w)*LambdaB*exp(-LambdaB*y)) ))}
```

U-values

```
U.lambdaB <- runif(1)
U.lambdaA<- runif(1)
U.w<- runif(1)
```

Count steps

```
REJLambdaB <- 1
REJw <- 1
REJLambdaA<-1
```

Initial points

```
LambdaB <- LambdaA<- w<- numeric(n)
LambdaA[1]<-0.5
LambdaB[1] <- 0.5
w[1] <- 0.5
```

Random walk MH algorithm, updating each component at a time:

```
for (t in 2:n){


 LambdaBprop<- rnorm(1,LB[t-1],0.5)
 wprop<- rnorm(1,w[t-1],0.5)
 LambdaAprop<- rnorm(1,LB[t-1],0.5)

logalpha1 = dmix(LambdaAprop,LambdaB[t-1],w[t-1])-dmix(LambdaA[t-1],LambdaB[t-
1],w[t-1])

logalpha2 = dmix(LambdaA[t-1],LambdaBprop,w[t-1])-dmix(LA[t-1],LB[t-1],w[t-
 1])




if (!is.null(log(U.lambdaB) > logalpha2))

{LambdaB[t] <- LambdaBprop}  ## accepted 

else{LambdaB[t] <- LambdaB[t-1] ##rejected
REJLambdaB<-REJLambdaB+1} 


if (!is.null(log(U.lambdaA) > logalpha1)) 

{LambdaA[t]<-LambdaAprop}

else {LambdaA[t]<-LambdaA[t-1]
REJLambdaA<-REJLambdaA+1}

 if (w[t]<0|w[t]>1) 

{w[t]<-w[t-1]}

else {w[t]<-wprop
REJw<-REJw+1}

}
```

Ultimately, I am having problems with my posterior since I keep getting either infinity or 0's when evaluating logalpha's. Note that i am looking to compare
log($\alpha(x'|x))$ with log(U). Any help to get this code to work ?

Comment: I think this question should migrated back to [X validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/316382/revisions) as the difficulty pertains to a poor understanding of the Metropolis algorithm, rather than to R coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really think that a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) means

```
lambdB[t]<- lambdB[t-1] + runif(1)
w[t]<- w[t-1] + runif(1)
lambdA[t] <- lambdB[t-1] + runif(1)
```

you should reconsider and invest into reading the bases of Markov chain theory and Markov chain Monte Carlo: At each iteration you add a Uniform U(0,1) variate to the current value. Therefore you *always* propose to *increase* the current value. Do you think this could ever produce an [ergodic Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity)?

There is also a mistake in `dmix`: since you work with the logarithm, remember that log(0)=-oo. And the quantities `logalpha1` and `logalpha2` are not updated correctly. And many more programming errors, like the incorrect use of `!is.null`... Anyway here is a corrected R code that works:

```
n<-100
y<- c(rexp(n))

#Logarithm of posterior:

dmix<-function(LambdaA,LambdaB,w){

  ifelse( (LambdaA<=0)|(LambdaB<=0)|(w<0)|(w>1) ,
    -1e50,log(w*LambdaA*LambdaB)-2*(LambdaA+LambdaB)+sum(log(w*LambdaA*exp(-
    LambdaA*y) + (1-w)*LambdaB*exp(-LambdaB*y))) )}

#Count steps

REJLambdaB <- 1
REJw <- 1
REJLambdaA<-1

#Initial points
N <- 1e4
LambdaB <- LambdaA <- w<- numeric(N)
LambdaA[1] <- LambdaB[1] <- w[1] <- 0.5

U.lambdaB <- runif(N)
U.lambdaA<- runif(N)
U.w <- runif(N)

for (t in 2:N){
LambdaBprop=rnorm(1,LambdaB[t-1],0.5)
LambdaAprop=rnorm(1,LambdaA[t-1],0.5)
wprop=rnorm(1,w[t-1],0.05)

logalpha2 = dmix(LambdaA[t-1],LambdaBprop,w[t-1])-dmix(LambdaA[t-1],LambdaB[t-1],w[t-1])

if ((log(U.lambdaB[t]) < logalpha2))
  {LambdaB[t] <- LambdaBprop}  ## accepted
else{LambdaB[t] <- LambdaB[t-1] ##rejected
     REJLambdaB<-REJLambdaB+1}

logalpha1 = dmix(LambdaAprop,LambdaB[t],w[t-1])-dmix(LambdaA[t-1],LambdaB[t],w[t-1])

if ((log(U.lambdaA[t]) < logalpha1)) 
  {LambdaA[t]<-LambdaAprop}
else {LambdaA[t]<-LambdaA[t-1]
  REJLambdaA<-REJLambdaA+1}

logw = dmix(LambdaA[t],LambdaB[t],wprop)-dmix(LambdaA[t],LambdaB[t],w[t-1])

if (w[t]<0|w[t]>1|(log(U.w[t])>logw))
    {w[t]<-w[t-1]}
else {w[t]<-wprop
    REJw<-REJw+1}

}
```

As shown by the outcome

[image]

the posterior produces a symmetric outcome in the Lambda's.

Comment: I see.. so I should be using normally distributed values (rnorm) for lambdaA and lambdaB so that it either decreases or increases? But then since w is over [0,1], i should use something different for that?

Comment: Thanks for advice. I still cannot get the code to work, i think there is an error in the posterior, any suggestions??

Comment: Ah, thanks, i copied the code wrong onto here. Still, i shall keep trying, i think it is a problem with my posterior because i need it to evaluate non-negative lambdas and w in [0,1]

Comment: This code still produces NAN's or Infinity for logalpha ?  it also produces the message: `Error in if ((log(U.lambdaB[t]) < logalpha2)) { : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` .... which is why i previously used is.null to remove such error

Comment: I think this was more of a coding bug(s) than: "you don't understand anything about MCMC".